# iOS gradient effect over UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I want to add gradient effect on a UILabel so it look like:

[image]

---

Please note the gradient effect on left and right corner.I've no clue how to do that.any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

**Edit**: - I tried with this code-

```
UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:20/255.0 green:157/255.0 blue:189/255.0 alpha:1.0];
NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],(id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors;
[gradientLayer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)];
[gradientLayer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];
[self.rightLabel.layer insertSublayer: gradientLayer atIndex:0];
```

But i'm getting like:

[image]

**Note:**

Gradient is added as background of Label but i want gradient effect as in 1st image (see label in right corner)

Comment: @bilios you need to set gradient image on both corner directly.I think it's best solution.

Comment: Ok thanks Neon.. can you please give me one more help, i want to scroll(slide) these three labels on click left/right arrow ?

Comment: Use array indices and change the text of the UILabel on clicking right and left arrow

Comment: Yes, i knew that, but i want to change the labels with sliding effect?

Comment: it looks a right path, but you need to use the gradient for masking the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is correct but you miss setting the frame that will be occupied by the `CAGradientLayer`..

And take note that you need to use color with alpha value, to avoid occurrence of black color.. ex:

`[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:0]`

or

`[[UIColor YourColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0]` instead of `[UIColor clearColor]`

And check this sample code, i've already tried this and works for me, hope this will work for you too.. Happy Coding.. :)

```
CAGradientLayer *rightGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
rightGradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, YourLabel.frame.size.width, YourLabel.size.height);
rightGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:0].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];
[rightGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.8, 0.9)];
[rightGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.9)];
[YourLabel.layer addSublayer:rightGradient];
```

Oh last thing, if you plan to add a gradient to the left just change

```
[rightGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.8, 0.9)];
[rightGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.9)];
```

to

```
[leftGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.2, 0.1)];
[leftGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.1)];
```

Here the sample output:

[image]

---

**Update as requested**

line 1: Simply allocation

```
CAGradientLayer *rightGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
```

line 2: `CAGradientLayer`s frame

```
rightGradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, YourLabel.frame.size.width, YourLabel.size.height);
```

This is very important, this sets the frame (same with UIView, etc) `CAGradientLayer`, meaning `origin.x` and `origin.y` is also considered..

line 3: `.colors`

```
rightGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:0].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];
```

When you assign array of color like whats in my example, color are arrange accordingly.. (color.alpha == 0) is in index 0 and (color.alpha == 1) is in index 1, and will be displayed left to right..

line 4: `setStartPoint`

```
[rightGradient setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.8, 0.9)];
```

> The start point corresponds to the first stop of the gradient. The
>   point is defined in the unit coordinate space and is then mapped to
>   the layer’s bounds rectangle when drawn.
>
> Default value is (0.5,0.0).

line 5: `setEndPoint`

```
[rightGradient setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.9)];
```

> The end point corresponds to the last stop of the gradient. The point
>   is defined in the unit coordinate space and is then mapped to the
>   layer’s bounds rectangle when drawn.
>
> Default value is (0.5,1.0).

```
[YourLabel.layer addSublayer:rightGradient];
```

And it was all discussed here.. [CAGradientLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAGradientLayer/colors)

About the color that you are asking you can use this: [UIColor Code Generator](http://uicolor.org)

But if you want to use hex string for color like `#ace123` you can use this method:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString withOpacity:(CGFloat)opacity
{
    unsigned rgbValue = 0;

    NSScanner *scanner;

    scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];

    scanner.scanLocation = ([hexString hasPrefix:@"#"]) ? 1 : 0;

    [scanner scanHexInt:&rgbValue];

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/255.0 green:((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/255.0 blue:(rgbValue & 0xFF)/255.0 alpha:opacity];

    return color;
}
```

^_^  **Cheers!**

Comment: can you please suggest correct color code for my example?

Comment: Ok. no need of color code. Instead can you please explain that how gradient works means how we should set the color etc or give me some good reference.

Comment: [Apples documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/) for how gradient works, hmm.. you want me to explain to you the `startPoint` and `endPoint`?

Comment: Thanks Oyeoj, just one more thing i want to clarify is it ok to use gradient in  in table cell ?I want to show it in table view i.e all the rows of my table have gradient effect a right side like picture in my question?

Comment: Yes, it's okay... but avoid redundant `-addSublayer`, one is enough.. :)

Comment: You mean one gradient sublayer per row?

Comment: Not exactly, what i mean is one `rightGradient`(for example) per row, since table is reusing every reload.. but adding gradient sublayer depends from what you want to accomplish.. Don't worry too much, using it in tablecell is all good.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add mask layer with mask image, it's should help:

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [CALayer layer];

maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.5f].CGColor;
maskLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"maskImage.png"] CGImage];

maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
maskLayer.frame = YourLabel.bounds;
YourLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

example mask image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain it more.. means how to use it and where to put this mask image?

Comment: i created sample code: [project link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6164uf8m2rq1t36/exampleMaskLayer.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
UIView * gradientView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:label.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:gradientView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:gradientView];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CAGradientLayer * gradientLayernavigationBar = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];

    gradientLayernavigationBar.frame = label.bounds;
    gradientLayernavigationBar.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor redColor  ] CGColor], nil];

    gradientLayernavigationBar.startPoint =CGPointMake(0, 1);
    gradientLayernavigationBar.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    gradientLayernavigationBar.opacity=1.0;
    [gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayernavigationBar atIndex:1];
```

Comment: Hi Pravin i'm getting gradient as background of my label, text is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of following demo. which is providing all effect on `UILabel`.

[FXLabel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel)

Output:
[image]

Here i am providing link because due to time complexity.

May this help you.

Comment: Lol... you are giving link of this question itself.

Comment: apologize, its typo mistake. kindly check updated link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assuming `UIColor.clearColor` works just fine. But it does not. It is a transparent black, which is different from a transparent white, or a transparent version of your blue. Along the gradient, your blue fades into **black** and loses opacity. You only want it to lose opacity. Hence you should use `[endColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0]` instead of `UIColor.clearColor`.

Also, this approach is bad when you don't have a solid background color. Consider not adding a gradient sublayer, but instead mask your view using a black to transparent gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the help of library [DrawingLabel](https://github.com/selim1377/DrawingLabel) without any CoreGraphics code:

```
DrawingGradient *gradient = [DrawingGradient new];
gradient.colorArray = @[[UIColor greenColor],[UIColor yellowColor],[UIColor cyanColor]];
gradient.locations  = @[@0,@0.3,@0.8];
gradient.gradientType = DrawingGradientTypeVertical;
```